# Find threshold for 1-D data

Tags: scikit-learn

I have a 1-D data. I have a binary classification problem. Points above a certain threshold belong to class 0 and points less than the threshold belong to class 1. I want to find that threshold. I don't want to pass this data to any classifier from sklearn, but want to use functionality like cross-validation and roc curve from sklearn. How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: So you have already result of classification and need to plot ROC to find optimal cut-off?

Comment: Yes. That is what I want.

Comment: Broad topic, standard method: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc.html